# Teleport and detonate 5 small atomic bombs that cause maximum panic and societal collapse?

Tags: warfare, weapons, nuclear-power

Suppose an evil scientist has a teleportation device and 5 atomic bombs, each one only as powerful as the one dropped on Hiroshima. What would be the best targets to create maximum panic to the humanity? Is it possible to cause population decline or make the governments revert to more simpler forms just by the panic alone?

Comment: some where well populated would bring in a nice death count for your villian

Comment: useful tool for all mad scientists: http://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/

Comment: In a movie you'd pick the major landmarks: Paris' Eiffeltower  Egypt's pyramids, the White House in the US, New York and of course the Golden Gate Bridge in San Francisco (it'll never survive the movie anyway)

Comment: There are 5 continents, and you have 5 atomic bombs, detonite each one on a continent where the polpulation is at max : global chaos guaranteed.

Comment: What do you mean "maximum chaos"? Maximum death count? Perhaps it would be more efficient to terrorize people by saying them you already have bombs in ALL major cities, and use the teleport device to "prove" it if necessary.

Comment: [Potential targets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_city#GaWC_study).

Comment: This doesn't seem to me to be about *building a world*. If it is, then please [edit] the question to clarify how it is, lest this is at risk of being closed as off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for some guidance.

Comment: This is about a new plot device to start an age of panic where my storyline can be possible. I don't know where should I post this so please close this question if you think it's not related to this community.

Comment: @RedRomanov One way to edit the question to be on-topic would be to restructure it as about the phrase "maximum chaos". That is, you might ask about what kinds of conditions cause widespread and preferably global disruption. If that gets useful answers, you may already be able to address your original question: what's the best way to teleport the A-bombs to produce one or more of the sorts of disruption you have learned about.

Comment: @CAgrippa Thank you for the suggestion. I already have the answer I am looking for, but I will see if I can make it on-topic as long as my English allows me to.

Comment: Jerusalem first... Mekka a week later... the Vatican after a while... all bombs jacketed with cobalt for intense fallout. Keep two in reserve for later. You have then inflamed three of the major world religions against each other.
 
Or you can start off with a target in India or Pakistan... that will heat things up rapidly before you do the targets where I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, just exploding a few bombs won't destroy the world. Luckily, you're an evil genius, aren't you. Use your bombs to deceive people, make them destroy themselves.

### Scenario one - WWIII

Detonate two bombs in two major nuclear-weapon states. Make them think a nuclear war have started, force them to use their nuclear weaponry on each other. Use your remaining three bombs to tinker the situation if needed.

### Scenario two - an ultimate terrorist

For maximum panic you don't actually need to bomb cities. Make people think you can do that any time you want. Show them their lives are no longer protected.

Claim you already have bombs in all major cities and can detonate them at will. Then use your first bomb to destroy a city you didn't choose. Say, bomb a winner of a world championship. Keep your teleportation device top secret, use it to prove your assertion.

Months later, governments are still unsuccessfully searching for your bombs, they lost people's trust, people are scared, panic is spreading through cities, crime rate is rising, all is going out of control.

Comment: I don't believe scenario three is actually possible, good answer otherwise

Comment: @Ciacciu why? Nuclear propulsion is a real thing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)

Comment: You'd need billions of bombs to alter the Moon orbit: https://www.quora.com/How-much-energy-would-it-take-to-crash-the-moon-into-the-Earth

Comment: But, by the way, you could try redirecting asteroids instead of the Moon, that seem plausible.

Comment: @enkryptor basically what Roux said, to actually do that you'd need a lot more energy than what is provided by 5 nukes.

Comment: anyways, the question will be closed